# What is the name of the 3D matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

The name of a variable in the $\mathbb{R}$ is called scalar.

Multiple scalars form a vector: $\mathbb{R}^n$

Two or more vectors form together a matrix: $\mathbb{R}^{n \times m }$

But what is the name of the 3 dimensional array of elments? ($\mathbb{R}^{n \times m \times k }$)

Comment: It can be called a multidimensional array or in some cases a tensor of order 3.

Comment: [Hypermatrix](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Hypermatrix.html)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

They are called Tensors, and in your case can be thought of as matrices whose entries are themselves matrices.  Any higher dimensions are also called tensors and are distinguished by their "order" (number of dimensions)

Comment: I think this answer is somewhat inaccurate. I think the difference between arrays and tensors is the difference between numbers and physical quantities, between thinking of vectors as lists of numbers vs thinking of them as arrows in space, or between matrices and linear transformations. An m×n×p 3D array is literally an association of numbers (or other objects) with indices, with all indices (i,j,k)∈{1...m}×{1...n}×{1...p}⊆ℕ³ so associated, while a tensor is an abstract object which can be represented with such array when a given basis/coordinate system is provided.

Answer (score 0):

``What is the name of a 3D matrices?''

To generalize let's ask, `What do you call a 3D array?' You could call it a $3^{rd}$ order array. So, what about a $3^{rd}$ order matrix? The term` matrix' implies that certain definitions are in place, regarding rank, determinant, trace, and matrix multiplication. An array on the other hand is just an organized list of objects, which doesn't necessarily have any stated mathematical rules.

If you have an interest in developing a theory of $3^{rd}$ or $n^{th}$ order matrices which involve extending the notions of determinant, trace, and $n^{th}$ order matrix multiplication then I would keep the matrix terminology. But if that is not the case, I would stick to the terminology to $n^{th}$--order arrays (hyphen optional).

In general, $n^{th}$--order arrays are not tensors. The space of $n^{th}$--order arrays are a superset of the space of tensor fields. An array is a tensor only if it obeys a certain law of coordinate transformation. The full tensor law can look very intimidating, so let's break it down starting with a vector. Imagine holding an actual arrow in your hand (as in ``bows and arrows''). The arrow has a certain length, and is pointing in some direction. The arrow is a vector. You may have heard that a vector is a first order tensor. Actually, that is not quite right. The arrow is there sitting in your hand without reference to any coordinate system. As soon as you erect a coordinate system to quantify it's orientation, then it becomes a first order tensor. You can now use the tensor transformation law to express the arrow in different coordinate systems. That rule is the \textit{chain rule}. I'm trying to avoid a certain complication concerning the difference between a vector, a contravariant vector, and a covariant vector. But to the point -- a third order transformation law involves the product of chain and/or inverse chains (three in total).

The third order contravariant tensor transformation equation is,

\begin{equation*}
  B^{ijk}(y) = \sum_{\alpha, \beta, \gamma}\frac{\partial y^i}{\partial x^{\alpha}}\frac{\partial y^j}{\partial x^{\beta}}\frac{\partial y^k}{\partial x^{\gamma}}A^{\alpha\beta\gamma}(x)
\end{equation*}

If $ \alpha, \beta, \gamma$ range from 1 to 3, then $B^{ijk}$ would be a $3\times 3\times 3$ tensor array (a cube). If they ranged from 1 to 4, then $B^{ijk}$ would be a $4\times 4\times 4$ tensor array (still a cube).

A third order array is not a contravariant tensor unless it obeys the above transformation law.

Comment: There is no transformation law when you’re talking about a fixed vector space with a basis and, say, a trilinear map on it. Same thing is true for matrices. They are perfectly fine linear algebra entities without the need for a transformation law. Sometimes physics just obliterates mathematics.

Answer (score 0):

There are no such think. Tensors are not the same to matrices, since depending on the order (number of indices) and dimension, the space where you life, you can find structures that are ddifferent to this.
However, specifically, a tensor of rank 3 in a tridimensional space, therefore an structure containing three indices, like the next presented, can be the closest structure you can use.

3-dimensional array
T = [
[[T_{111}, T_{112}, T_{113}],
[T_{121}, T_{122}, T_{123}],
[T_{131}, T_{132}, T_{133}]],

[[T_{211}, T_{212}, T_{213}],
[T_{221}, T_{222}, T_{223}],
[T_{231}, T_{232}, T_{233}]],

[[T_{311}, T_{312}, T_{313}],
[T_{321}, T_{322}, T_{323}],
[T_{331}, T_{332}, T_{333}]]
]

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).